# Repeating Records Writing Output in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, if-statement, output

I'm trying to write a Perl script to do the following:

I have a file that contains a list of files called "filelist.txt" (i.e. file1.txt, file2.txt, etc.),
along with a column that contains numeric values that need to be read & used to update the corresponding
row in each of the files.

Note: All files are tab delimited.

filelist.txt (input)

```
file1.txt 1.dogs, 3.cats, 5.frog
file2.txt 2.lion
file3.txt 4.swan, 5.snake
file4.txt 3.giraffe, 4.turtle, 5.monkey
file5.txt 4.tiger
```

Each file has 'x' number of rows:

file1.txt (input)

```
1 dogs word2 word3
2 word1 word2 word3
3 cats word2 word3
4 word1 word2 word3
5 frog word2 word3
```

What I need to do is read column 1 in "filelist.txt" to get the filename (i.e. file1.txt). Then read column 2 to get the row numbers (i.e. 1.word, 3.word, 5.word). Once I have the row numbers, I need to open "file1.txt" and for each row number that matches the number(s) extracted from "filelist.txt", print each row in "file1.txt" (as shown below), where the extracted number from "filelist.txt" matches the row number in "file1.txt". In this example, "1" from "1.dogs" matches row 1, "3" from "3.cats" matches row "3", "5" from "5.frog" matches row "5". This needs to be done for every file in "filelist.txt".

file1.tmp (output)

```
<strike>1</strike> <strike>dogs</strike> <strike>word2</strike> <strike>word3</strike>
2 word1 word2 word3
<strike>3</strike> <strike>cats</strike> <strike>word2</strike> <strike>word3</strike>
4 word1 word2 word3
<strike>5</strike> <strike>frog</strike> <strike>word2</strike> <strike>word3</strike>
```

OUTPUT REQUIRED (based on files in filelist.txt).

```
file1.txt needs rows 1, 3, 5 to be updated. 2, 4 stay as is.
file2.txt needs row 2 to be updated. 1, 3, 4, 5 stay as is.
file3.txt needs rows 4, 5 to be updated. 1, 2, 3.
file4.txt needs rows 3, 4, 5 to be updated. 1, 2 stay as is.
file5.txt needs row 4 to be updated. 1, 2, 3, 5 stay as is.
```

SCRIPT

```
use Cwd;
$dir = getcwd;

$nofile = "FILE NOT FOUND";
$strike = "<>";
$tab = "    ";
my $filelist = "filelist.list";

open INFILE, "$dir/$filelist" or die "$nofile\n";

while (my $line=<INFILE>) 
{
   chomp($line);
   my ($filename, $rownum) = split /\t/, $line;

   @rowarray = split(/, /, $rownum);
   my $arraysize = @rowarray;

   open INFILE2, "$dir/$filename" or die "$nofile\n"; 
   $filename =~ s/.txt//; 
   $tmpfilename = $filename;
   open (OUTFILE, ">$dir/$tmpfilename.tmp"); 

   while (my $line2=<INFILE2>) 
   {
      chomp ($line2);
      my ( $fn, $col1, $col2, $col3 ) = split (/\t/, $line2);

      for ($i = 0; $i < $arraysize; $i++) 
      {
         $scratched = $rowarray[$i];
         my ($substring2) = $scratched =~ /(.*)?\./;

         if ($substring2 == $fn) 
         {
            print "Match: $substring2 == $fn\n\n";
            print OUTFILE "$strike$fn$strike$tab$strike$col1$strike$tab$strike$col2$strike$tab$strike$col3$strike\n";
         }
         elsif ($substring2 != $fn) 
         {
            print "No match: $substring2 != $fn\n\n";
            print OUTFILE "$fn$tab$col1$tab$col2$tab$col3\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
close (INFILE);
close (INFILE2);
close (OUTFILE);
```

CURRENT OUTPUT (from file1.txt as input)

```
<>1<> <>dogs<> <>word2<> <>word3<>
1 dogs word2 word3
1 dogs word2 word3
2 word1 word2 word3
2 word1 word2 word3
2 word1 word2 word3
3 cats word2 word3
<>3<> <>cats<> <>word2<><>word3<>
3 cats word2 word3
4 word1 word2 word3
4 word1 word2 word3
4 word1 word2 word3
5 frog word2 word3
5 frog word2 word3
<>5<> <>frog<> <>word2<> <>word3<>
```

Been working on this for a few days and unfortunately, I cannot see how to get this to work properly.

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Billy J.

Comment: Please always use `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code to catch typos and other problems, and indent your code when you show it to other people for help. It's very hard to read like this. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Where are the dogs and cats coming from? You don't have that in your example input. It's very hard to follow what your code is supposed to do. This wall of text of explanation is not very clear. What do the `word` parts in the filelist mean? Are they relevant at all, or do you only need the numbers to get the right lines?

Comment: as much as I would lve to help, this is not very clear. you say you want "need `row` 1,2..." but do you mean `columns`? also you have `input file` and `input file` both differ, what reference do they have towards each other? Your expected result contains words such as dogs and frogs these are not in the original input?

Comment: Sorry guys. The data has been corrected. The words, dogs, cats, etc. are irrelevant. They are there just to show the rows that need to be updated. I only need numbers to get the correct lines/rows. So for file1.txt, row 1, row 3 & row 5 need to be updated. Note: The row number is in column 1. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't you be closing `INFILE2` and `OUTFILE` inside the outer while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing every member of the array with each line and outputting to the temporary file if it matches or not so you end up with multiple copies of each line. The easiest solution to fix your code is to have a variable track whether or not you get a match and once outside the for loop, you can print the line appropriately.

```
  my $match = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $arraysize; $i++) 
  {
     $scratched = $rowarray[$i];
     my ($substring2) = $scratched =~ /(.*)?\./;

     if ($substring2 == $fn) 
     {
        print "Match: $substring2 == $fn\n\n";
        $match = 1;
        last; # No need checking the rest of the array at this point
     }
     else # elsif was overkill - it'll either match or not
     {
        print "No match: $substring2 != $fn\n\n";
     }
  }
  if ($match)
  {
     print OUTFILE "$strike$fn$strike$tab$strike$col1$strike$tab$strike$col2$strike$tab$strike$col3$strike\n";
  } else {
     print OUTFILE "$fn$tab$col1$tab$col2$tab$col3\n";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Chris Turner. This worked liked a charm. If you're ever in Sydney, Australia, give me a call. I owe you a few beers. Cheers!